# unable to change 64bit architecture to 32 bit architecture while using dpkg command

Tags: dpkg, skype, 32-bit

i am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit architecture.
i want to install skype in order to do this first i need to convert 64 to 32 bit architecture.. 
so i type the command `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and it not working..
and showing like this...

```
(satyam@satyam-Vostro:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
 [sudo] password for satyam: 
 dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

 Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
 Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
 Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
 Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
 Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
```

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or`more' !)

plz help me out to fix this problem...

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04 the option is

```
--force-architecture
```

The

```
 --add-architecture
```

was added in 12.10.

- [man dpkg 12.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg.1.html).
- [man dpkg 12.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html).

Comment: it is not working     --force-architecture                                                        dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !